# 水槽にいる魚を上からカメラで撮り、その位置をトラッキングしたいのですがどのような方法が良いでしょうか？

Tags: opencv, 画像, camera

水槽を上部からカメラで映してその映像から魚のいる位置をトラッキングしたいのですが、どのような方法が適しているのでしょうか？
opencvを使ってhsv変換し、その色でトラッキングをしてみたのですが、光の加減によって不安定になったり、影に入ると認識されなくなったりしてあまりうまく行きません
何か良い方法があればおしえてくださると助かります。

Answer (score 5):

卒業研究でまさにそういうことをやっていました。
プログラミングのQ&Aサイトである stackoverflow にはふさわしくない回答ですが、プログラミングで解決することに拘らないことです。
画像処理とは実世界のものを扱う工学ですから、ソフトウェアだけではなく、ハードウェアなど実世界についての知識のほうがより重要になります。
一般的な回答は難しいのですが、
例えば、カメラと対象物の配置の仕方、カメラとレンズの選び方、照明の当て方など、撮影技術の基礎知識。
さらに魚を観察するなら、対象の魚の習性や飼育の知識も重要になります。

今回のような話なら、照明の当て方や水槽の形状を工夫することが正攻法だと思います。